# Update a table with flask and flask socket io dynamically

Tags: html, python-2.7, flask, flask-socketio

First time trying `flask` and `socket` both are impressive but am stuck with a simple problem.

1. I have an `list` of data coming from my btest module and can render a `html table`. This table will need to be updated with new values that come at certain intervals.
2. I am using `flask socketio` to update the table with new values but am not sure how to do it. Below is python code and I can render the initial table. After which I receive `500 error` as socket cannot connect.
3. If I disable flask rendering I am able to connect and grab table data but do not know how to post it to `html`(*HTML code below*). Thank you in advance. HTML code has additional messages as I was trying to debug.
4. If there is an easier way to conduct the task I am all ears. Thank you for the support.

   ```
   from flask import Flask, render_template
   from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send
   from flask_table import Table, Col
   import time
   import btest

   def ntable():
       dataz,peername=btest.send(6*1024)
       NAME,ID,S1,S2,S3,ONLINE,IPConn=btest.status(dataz,peername)
       data = dict( NAME=[NAME],ID=[ID],S1=[S1],S2=[S2],S3=[S3],ONLINE=    [ONLINE],IPConn=[IPConn])

       class ItemTable(Table):
           NAME=Col('NAME')
           ID=Col('ID')
           S1=Col('S1')
           S2=Col('S2')
           S3=Col('S3')
           ONLINE=Col('ONLINE')
           IPConn=Col('IPConn')
       items = [dict( NAME=NAME,ID=ID,S1=S1,S2=S2,S3=S3,ONLINE=ONLINE,IPConn=IPConn)]


       table = ItemTable(items)
       s=(table.__html__())
       t=s.replace('<table>','<table class="table table-hover">')
       return t

       f=open("table.txt",'w')
       f.write(t)
       f.close()
       socketio.emit('message',{'table': t})

   def ntabrefresh():
       dataz,peername=btest.send(6*1024)
       NAME,ID,S1,S2,S3,ONLINE,IPConn=btest.status(dataz,peername)
       while S2=="All Downloads Completed.":
       data = dict( NAME=[NAME],ID=[ID],S1=[S1],S2=[S2],S3=[S3],ONLINE=[ONLINE],IPConn=[IPConn])

           class ItemTable(Table):
               NAME=Col('NAME')
               ID=Col('ID')
               S1=Col('S1')
               S2=Col('S2')
               S3=Col('S3')
               ONLINE=Col('ONLINE')
               IPConn=Col('IPConn')
           items = [dict( NAME=NAME,ID=ID,S1=S1,S2=S2,S3=S3,ONLINE=ONLINE,IPConn=IPConn)]

           table = ItemTable(items)
           s=(table.__html__())
           t=s.replace('<table>','<table class="table table-hover">')

           socketio.emit('message',{'table': t})

   app = Flask(__name__)
   app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
   socketio = SocketIO(app)

   @app.route('/')
   def index():
       t=ntable()
       return render_template('mytest0.html',s=t)

   @socketio.on('connect')
   def test_connect():
       print 'client and I are one'
       socketio.emit('message')
       time.sleep(3)
       ntabrefresh()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       socketio.run(app)
   ```

   ```html
       <html><head>
           <title>SMPV Status</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
           <script src="static/jquery.js"></script>
           <script src="static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>

           <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
               $(document).ready(function() {
                   // Use a "/test" namespace.
                   // An application can open a connection on multiple namespaces, and
                   // Socket.IO will multiplex all those connections on a single
                   // physical channel. If you don't care about multiple channels, you
                   // can set the namespace to an empty string.
                   //namespace = '/test';
                   // Connect to the Socket.IO server.
                   // The connection URL has the following format:
                   //     http[s]://<domain>:<port>[/<namespace>]
                   var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
                   // Event handler for new connections.
                   // The callback function is invoked when a connection with the
                   // server is established.
                   socket.on('connect', function() {
                       socket.emit('server said hello');
                       console.log('In connect block sir')
                   });

                   socket.on('message',function(msg){
                     console.log("Recieved table");
                     console.log(msg);
                     $('#tbl').append(msg);

                   });

                   // Event handler for server sent data.
                   // The callback function is invoked whenever the server emits data
                   // to the client. The data is then displayed in the "Received"
                   // section of the page.
                   socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {
                       $('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('Received #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data).html());
                   });
                   // Interval function that tests message latency by sending a "ping"
                   // message. The server then responds with a "pong" message and the
                   // round trip time is measured.
                   var ping_pong_times = [];
                   var start_time;
                   window.setInterval(function() {
                       start_time = (new Date).getTime();
                       socket.emit('my_ping');
                   }, 1000);
                   // Handler for the "pong" message. When the pong is received, the
                   // time from the ping is stored, and the average of the last 30
                   // samples is average and displayed.
                   socket.on('my_pong', function() {
                       var latency = (new Date).getTime() - start_time;
                       ping_pong_times.push(latency);
                       ping_pong_times = ping_pong_times.slice(-30); // keep last 30 samples
                       var sum = 0;
                       for (var i = 0; i < ping_pong_times.length; i++)
                           sum += ping_pong_times[i];
                       $('#ping-pong').text(Math.round(10 * sum / ping_pong_times.length) / 10);
                   });
                   // Handlers for the different forms in the page.
                   // These accept data from the user and send it to the server in a
                   // variety of ways
                   $('form#emit').submit(function(event) {
                       socket.emit('my_event', {data: $('#emit_data').val()});
                       return false;
                   });
                   $('form#broadcast').submit(function(event) {
                       socket.emit('my_broadcast_event', {data: $('#broadcast_data').val()});
                       return false;
                   });
                   $('form#join').submit(function(event) {
                       socket.emit('join', {room: $('#join_room').val()});
                       return false;
                   });
                   $('form#leave').submit(function(event) {
                       socket.emit('leave', {room: $('#leave_room').val()});
                       return false;
                   });
                   $('form#send_room').submit(function(event) {
                       socket.emit('my_room_event', {room: $('#room_name').val(), data: $('#room_data').val()});
                       return false;
                   });
                   $('form#close').submit(function(event) {
                       socket.emit('close_room', {room: $('#close_room').val()});
                       return false;
                   });
                   $('form#disconnect').submit(function(event) {
                       socket.emit('disconnect_request');
                       return false;
                   });
               });
           </script>
       </head>

          <body style="height:1445px">

            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <div id="tbl">
              {% block body %}
              {{s|safe}}
              {% endblock %}


            </div>


       </body></html>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look at the example code in the Flask-SocketIO repository. That example shows the network latency in the page, and updates it at regular intervals. You can model your situation after that part of the example.

The main problem you have in your code is that you are doing everything in the `connect` callback. But as you can read in the documentation, the Socket.IO connection is only established when the connect callback returns `True`. Since you never return from that function, the connection is not made. The example I referenced above uses a background thread to conduct interval updates, that is a better model that I think will work for you.

Comment: Yes this was super helpful thank you. Only issue now is whether it can run on the network as opposed to localhost?

Comment: Sure. Why would it not run on the public network? There is no difference.

Comment: Did you solve this? Can please post your code solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219998/json-parse-socket-io-to-html-table Maybe this example can assist you further.