# Json Parse Socket.io to HTML Table

Tags: json, parsing, socket.io

I have sample from Socket.io which is display price ticker of cryptocurrency. I try to find way to parse this socket to HTML table but still not find the resources. Here is the sample code using socket.io javascript :

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id='trade'> open console </div>
        </body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var socket = io.connect('https://coincap.io');
            socket.on('trades', function (tradeMsg) {
                console.log(tradeMsg);
                document.getElementById('trade').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tradeMsg)
            })
        </script>

    </html>
```

Here is sample of output string from above code :

{"coin":"BTC","exchange_id":"bitfinex","market_id":"BTC_USD","message":{"coin":"BTC","msg":{"cap24hrChange":0.98,"long":"Bitcoin","mktcap":112062520162.10434,"perc":0.98,"price":6454.5,"shapeshift":true,"short":"BTC","supply":17254075,"usdVolume":4485870675.82,"volume":4485870675.82,"vwapData":6452.35557294237,"vwapDataBTC":6452.35557294237}},"msg":{"cap24hrChange":0.98,"long":"Bitcoin","mktcap":112062520162.10434,"perc":0.98,"price":6454.5,"shapeshift":true,"short":"BTC","supply":17254075,"usdVolume":4485870675.82,"volume":4485870675.82,"vwapData":6452.35557294237,"vwapDataBTC":6452.35557294237},"NODE_ID":1,"WORKER_ID":"3002"}

I want to parse above value to HTML table like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>COIN</td>
    <td>EXCHANGE</td>
    <td>MARKET</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>value coin here</td>
    <td>value exchange here</td>
    <td>value market here</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Any idea how to parse json from socket to html table?? thanks for help.

Comment: Can you give an example for `tradeMsg` as retrieved from `coincap.io`?

Comment: thanks. i just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mere parsing into an HTML table is rather easy. Note, that the following code makes use of template strings. It also has no checks in place to verify the message or the existence of the table. So you might need to add those.

```js
function toTable( msg ) {
  document.getElementById( 'results' )
          .insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend',
            `<tr><td>${msg.coin}</td><td>${msg.exchange_id}</td><td>${msg.market_id}</td></tr>`
          );
}

toTable( {"coin":"BTC","exchange_id":"bitfinex","market_id":"BTC_USD","message":{"coin":"BTC","msg":{"cap24hrChange":0.98,"long":"Bitcoin","mktcap":112062520162.10434,"perc":0.98,"price":6454.5,"shapeshift":true,"short":"BTC","supply":17254075,"usdVolume":4485870675.82,"volume":4485870675.82,"vwapData":6452.35557294237,"vwapDataBTC":6452.35557294237}},"msg":{"cap24hrChange":0.98,"long":"Bitcoin","mktcap":112062520162.10434,"perc":0.98,"price":6454.5,"shapeshift":true,"short":"BTC","supply":17254075,"usdVolume":4485870675.82,"volume":4485870675.82,"vwapData":6452.35557294237,"vwapDataBTC":6452.35557294237},"NODE_ID":1,"WORKER_ID":"3002"} );
```

```html
<table id="results">
  <tr>
    <th>COIN</th>
    <th>EXCHANGE</th>
    <th>MARKET</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

On the other hand, updates will be more interesting, as you have to create a key for each entry and keep track of whether there already a row for that entry or not.

Comment: Thanks. It works bro. But there is still a problem because "insertAdjacentHTML" always add new row. I just want update the value inside the row instead of adding new row.

Comment: @Harris This is what I mentioned at the end. You can add the key as a `data-` property, then use `document.querySelector()` to get that row and `nth-child` or a dedicated class to find the respective cell and update it.

Answer (score 0):

based on above answer, i just modify the code to make it work without adding new row. Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='trade'></div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

  function toTable( data ) {
  document.getElementById( 'results' ).innerHTML = "<tr><th>COIN</th><th>EXCHANGE</th><th>MARKET</th><th>PRICE</th></tr>";
  document.getElementById( 'results' ).innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + data.coin + "</td><td>" + data.exchange_id.toUpperCase() + "</td><td> " + data.market_id + "</td><td>" + data.message.msg.price + "</td></tr>";
}

        var socket = io.connect('https://coincap.io');
        socket.on('trades', function (tradeMsg) {
            console.log(tradeMsg);
            //document.getElementById('trade').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tradeMsg);
            toTable(tradeMsg);


        })

    </script>

</html>

<table  border="1" id="results"></table>
```